# Haskell Higher order filter function

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter (\x -> x % 2 == 0) [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I have written the above piece of code. I want to take a list anon numbers return numbers from the list that meet the conditions of the boolean expression x % 2 == 0

When I run this code I get an error

Parse error: naked expression at top level
Perhaps you intended to use TemplateHaskell

Being new to haskell I am not sure what to do

Comment: You are trying to *call* `filter`, not define it.

Comment: Are you trying to define a new function called `filter`, or are you trying to use `filter` from the prelude?

Comment: @Brian trying to use filter from the prelude. the previous definition define filters as a function that take a list and returns another list that meets the boolean condition

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the type signature (`filter` is already defined) and use the call to define a new variable.

```
even_numbers = filter (\x -> x % 2 == 0) [1,2,3,4,5]
```

(By the way, `even` is predefined; you can just write `filter even [1,2,3,4,5]`.)

If you are trying to define a *new* version of `filter` that hard-codes the predicate:

```
even_numbers :: [a] -> [a]
even_numbers xs = filter even xs
```

Comment: Don't forget that in Haskell you should use `mod` or `rem`. `%` is not in Prelude, but is most commonly the constructor for `Ratio`s in Data.Ratio. Or, you can use the built-in function `even` directly.

Comment: Your error means you have declared a type signature `filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]` without defining the accompanying function `filter`. But since you are trying to use the `filter` from prelude, you will not be defining it yourself and should not include the type signature. Type signatures are just for defining variables, not for calling them.